# ¿Como determinar si la celda que ha cambiado de una google sheet esta en una lista y cómo poner un disparador?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Soy nuevo en google scripts y el manejo de eventos y no me aclaro con la API.

Estoy mirando de crear un script que monitoriza determinadas celdas de una hoja concreta de un libro de google sheets. Estas celdas, contienen una formula que depende del contenido de un rango de otras celdas que el usuario modifica manualmente. Así, cuando el usuario edita las últimas, las primeras cambian.

La idea es que si el valor de alguna del las celdas (C61:C66) cambia por encima de un umbral prefijado (0.25) (***el usuario NO las modifica directamente***) se envie un e-mail. Pej: la celda C61 contiene la fórmula:

```
=CONTAR.SI(D61:61, "No")/E$67
```

Lo que se pretende es que si tras cambiar ***manualmente*** alguna celda de D61:61 el valor de C61 es mayor que 0.25, el sistema envíe un par de e-mails. Lo mismo pasaría con las celdas C62:C66

Por ahora lo que tengo es:

```
function sheetTracker() {

// Version 2.0

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Obtenemos a quehoja del libro pertenece la celda que ha cambiado
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); // Obtenemos la celda que ha cambiado
var celda = cell.getA1Notation(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la celda que ha cambiado

var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var hoja = currentSheet.getName(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la hoja en la que ha cambiado la celda

var editRange = {top : 61,bottom : 66, column : 3}; // Celdas a verificar: C61:C66

// Si no se ha modificado una celda de la hoja de asistencia que toca salimos

if (hoja != "Mi hoja") return;  

// Si las celdas modificadas estan fuera de rango salimos
var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
if (Number(thisRow) < editRange.top || Number(thisRow) > editRange.bottom) return;

var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
if (Number(thisCol) != editRange.column) return;

var range = e.range; // La celda que se ha cambiado
var columna = range.getColumn(); // La columna en la que esta la celda que ha cambiado
var fila = range.getRow(); // La fila en la que esta la celda que ha cambiado
var valor = Number(range.getValue()); // El nuevo valor de la celda
var valor = Number(ss.getActiveCell().getValue());

var alumno = range.offset(0,2);
var email = range.offset(0,-2);
var yes = range.offset(0,1);
var justified = range.offset(0,-1); 

if ( celda == 'C61' && valor > 0.25) {
   MailApp.sendEmail(email, subjecta, messagea); 
   MailApp.sendEmail(director, subjectd, messaged);
}
```

Mis preguntas son:

1)-¿Es posible definir una lista de celdas a comprobar tal que 
['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']

y hacer algo como en python "celda in ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']

2)-El "e.range" viene de intentar usar una función onEdit(e) donde "e" es un evento. Sin embargo, estoy intentando no usar un evento. No me queda claro el uso de disparadores. Parece que hay funciones "reservadas" que se "auto-disparan" como "onEdit(e)" y "onChange(e)" cuando se edita o cambia una celda y otras que no, necesitando de disparadores "externos" ¿qué opciones tengo?

Comment: Sugiero que mejores la redacción de "Estas celdas, cambian su valor en respuesta a un determinado valor de otrs celdas. Así, si el cuando el usuario edita las últimas, las primeras cambian." quizás ampliarlo un poco para que no tengas que publicar una nueva pregunta. En particular especifica si existe si cada una de las celdas indicadas depende de una celda que modificará el usuario manualmente y si es así, cuales son estas. Podría ser útil que incluyeras una versión simplificada de las fórmulas de las celdas indicadas.

Comment: Hice un cambio a mi respuesta para considerar lo agregado en la rev. 3 de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

## Respuesta corta

De la [rev 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/190038/3) de la pregunta

> Lo que se pretende es que si tras cambiar alguna manualmente alguna celda de D61:61 el valor de C61 es mayor que 0.25, el sistema envie un par de e-mails. Lo mismo pasaria con las celdas C62:C66

```
function onEdit(e){
  var fila = e.range.getRow();
  var columna = e.range.getColumn();
  if(columna < 3 && fila !== 61) return; // Salir cuando rango editado no sea D61:61 
  // Hacer lo que se tenga que hacer cuando el rango editado sea válido.
}
```

---

Código previo

```
function onEdit(e){
  var celda = e.range.getA1Notation();
  var fila = celda.getRow();
  // Asumiendo que las celdas modificadas por el usuario a monitorear son
  var lista = ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66'];
  if(lista.indexOf(celda)){
    //Poner aquí lo que hay que hacer si la celda está en lista
  } else {
    // Poner aquí lo que hay que hacer si la celda no está enl a lista
  }
}
```

## Respuesta amplia

Con respecto a lo indicado en la cita incluida arriba, se puede usar un activador al editar o al cambiar para verificar lo que ocurre en otra parte del de la hoja, como sería un cálculo realizado por fórmulas

NOTA: Uno debe tener presente la asincronía entre el evento y el recálculo. Cuando son cálculos sencillos es muy probable que estos sean más rápidos que Apps Script. Puede usarse SpreadsheetApp.sleep(millisegundos) para esperar un determinado tiempo o bien podrian guardarse los valores previos en propiedades y usar algo como "exponential backoff" para tener un cierto grado de tolerancia a lo que demore el recálculo.

---

Sobre el código, la variable `e` no está definida. No está claro cómo pasas esa variable desde una función onEdit(e), pero seguramente no es realmente relevante para las preguntas que haces.

---

> 1)-¿Es posible definir una lista de celdas a comprobar tal que
>   ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']
>
> y hacer algo como en python "celda in
>   ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']

Por un lado Google Apps Script está basado en JavaScript, así que puedes definer la lista de celdas a comprobar como un array de referencias prácticamente como lo has scrito

```
var lista = ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66'];
```

Luego puedes usar [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations) para obtener un objeto [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) o puedes usar los métodos de Array como indexOf, each, some, every, map o bien usar bucles como for y while junto con algunos de los `getRange(a1Notation)`, ya sea de [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) o de [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) para hacer cosas con los elementos de la lista.

> 2)-El "e.range" viene de intentar usar una función onEdit(e) donde "e"
>   es un evento. Sin embargo, estoy intentando no usar un evento. No me
>   queda claro el uso de disparadores. Parece que hay funciones
>   "reservadas" que se "auto-disparan" como "onEdit(e)" y "onChange(e)"
>   cuando se edita o cambia una celda y otras que no, necesitando de
>   disparadores "externos" ¿qué opciones tengo?

Los nombres de función reservados se indican en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/. Estos se utilizan para **activadores simples**. `onChange` no es uno de ellos. Los **activadores instalables** se configuran desde el menú Editar desde donde se puede seleccionar cualquier función del ámbito global del proyecto siendo editado.

Los indicadores instalables se indican en https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable.

En las hojas de cálculo para ejecutar una función cuando se edita una función de pudes usar un activador simple `onEdit`, o bien una activador instalable *al editar* o *al cambiar* una hoja de cálculo.

Notas:

1. Evita usar usar el nombre onEdit para un activador instalable pues podría ejecutarse doblemente, al ser disparado como activador simple y como activador instalable.
2. Tu activador instalable al cambiar puede llamar una función con nombre onChange o con cualquier otro nombre, pero evitar llamar una función llamada onEdit por lo indicado en la nota anterior.
3. Los activadores al editar o al cambiar sólo son disparados por ediciones de celdas o la hoja de cálculo realizadas por el usuario según el caso. Los cambios de valores debido a recálculo no disparan estos activadores. Si esto es lo que estás buscando, deberás usar un activador dirigido por tiempo (time-driven trigger) o una función desde una barra lateral, diálogo o algo externo que esté monitoreando los cambios y actúe en consecuencia.

Comment: Gracias Rubén por la ayuda. El primer punto queda casi resuelto, me miro la documentación que me pasas. Lo que pretendo es una lista para evitar tener que poner seis "if" uno tras otro para ver si la celda que ha cambiado es una de las seis de la lista. Por ello he pensado en la estrategia de crear la lista y mirar si la celda editada pertenece a esa lista. Luego, solo tendría que añadir "&& valor > umbral)" y enviar el email.

Comment: @isg: DND. Aprovechando que haces referencia a un punto, en tus próximas consultas incluye sólo una pregunta de otra forma podría ser calificada como demasiado amplia en particular si está relacionada con etiquetas populares como [tag:javascript].

Comment: @isg Tu nuevo comentario más parece una pregunta de seguimiento que una solicitud de aclaración por lo que debería ser publicada como una nueva pregunta. Por cierto, agregué una "respuesta corta" en la que uso indexOf (no lo había mencionado previamente).

Comment: Gracias por añadir la respuesta corta, sin duda me ayuda bastante. Una imagen vale más que mil palabras.

Comment: ¿El uso de `onEdit(e)` que haces en tu respuesta corta me ahorraría tener que usar un activador externo para monitorizar si una de las seis celdas de la lista ha cambiado debido a que el usuario ha editado otras celdas?

Comment: @isg: Depende. Como mencioné en un comentario a tu pregunta sería bueno que mejoraras la redacción al menos del enunciado señalado y que agregues más datos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ya tengo una versión más depurada de lo que quiero hacer:

```
function sheetTracker() { 

// Version 2.0

var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Obtenemos a que libro pertenece la celda que ha cambiado
var hoja = libro.getActiveSheet().getName(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la hoja en la que ha cambiado la celda
var lista = ['C61','C62','C63','C64','C65','C66']; // Celdas a monitorizar
var celda = libro.getActiveCell().getA1Notation(); // Obtenemos el nombre de la celda que ha cambiado
var valor = Number(libro.getActiveCell().getValue()); // El nuevo valor de la celda

// Si no se ha modificado una celda de la hoja de asistencia que toca salimos

if (hoja != "Mi hoja") return; 

if (lista.indexOf(celda) && valor > 0.25) { 
       var fila     = libro.getActiveCell().getRow();
       var columna  = libro.getActiveCell().getColumn();
       var persona  = libro.getRange(fila,columna+2).getValue().toString();
       var email    = libro.getRange(fila,columna-2).getValue().toString();
       var yes      = libro.getRange(fila,columna+1).getValue();
       var justfied = libro.getRange(fila,columna-1).getValue();

       MailApp.sendEmail(email, subjecta, messagea); 
       MailApp.sendEmail(director, subjectd, messaged);


} else {
      return;
}
}
```

Al final, me he decantado por una activador instalable (descartando el uso de la función "onEdit(e)" y su evento e ). Para instalar el activador instalaria un activador:  on edit (ir a recursos >hoja actual>activadores>añadir nuevo disparador) y autorizar el script.

Pero me surge la siguiente duda: ¿es correcta la manera de desplazarme a otra celda para definir las variables: persona,email y justified, o debería usar la función offset()?

Comment: Está muy bien que hayas compartido tu solución, aunque sea provisional, como respuesta, pero no deberías incluir en su redacción seguimiento esperando que sea respondida. Sería buena idea que publicaras una nueva pregunta e incluyeras el enlace a la misma.

Comment: @Rubén lo he hecho así por que considero que la solución no está terminada y de hecho, cuando intento instalar un activador, no me deja: Me dice "Se ha producido un error inesperado ignorar" (sin darme más información de qué está causando el error) y no me deja instalar un activador. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto la función no me da error. ¿alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Sería conveniente que publicaras una nueva pregunta sobre el error para que incluyas más detalles como el nombre y versión del sistema operativo y navegador, si usas extensiones, y si ya intentaste crear el activador instalable usando tu navegador en modo privado/incógnito.